# The model backing the <Database> context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I have a code first MVC site and I'm getting this error, but I have the Auto Migrations turned on as per the code below:

```
namespace KnightOwlMVC.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<KnightOwlMVC.Models.KnightOwlContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(KnightOwlMVC.Models.KnightOwlContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //
        }
    }
}
```

I've run the following to update the DB, but I'm still getting the same error:

```
Update-Database -ConnectionStringName DefaultConnection
```

Comment: Run update-database -verbose to see what it's trying to do or switch to a manual migration. You can also run update-database -force to force the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this in the end by doing it a really down and ditry way and deleting the database and starting again. Seeing as it's an app in development I can afford to, but obviously I wouldn't recommend this way for production.